# how to make fopen works if working directory and source directory are different and file reside share the source directory?

Tags: c

I have a CSV file to read, which is in same directory of cpp. While building the code, exe get generated in different folder (out folder itself get generated). I know while running program current working directory is directory of exe thats why fopen returns null. How can i get the path of cpp and pass it in fopen to make it work. Note: "I can not use iostream"

Comment: Who prevents you from putting the absolute path to the `csv file`?

Comment: Or a proper relative path?

Comment: I am running my program through cmd. Now problem is exe get generated in "out" folder, which I dont have before running the program. so i can not give absolute path.

Comment: i tried with dirent.h, to get directory path of cpp, but getting compilation error that dirent.h doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define PATH "/home/logan/path_to_cpp_file/"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   char file2open[256];

   sprintf (file2open, "%sfoo.csv", PATH);
   fd = open (file2open, O_RDONLY)
      ......
   close (fd);

}
```

This way it will search for that file in cpp file folder.

---

Or if you do not want to give the path of cpp file folder as above hard coded then you can use some macro like `__FILE__` which would you give the path of cpp file.

```
char* fileName = basename(__FILE__);
```

---

Or anothe way is to pass the file path as argument to command.

Comment: Thanks Jeegar.. actually i dont want to give hard coded path. I will try this macro btw and let you know if things works for me

Comment: __FILE__ it will give you full path of that cpp file then using basename() you can get it upto folder name...Updated demo code in answer ...

Comment: jeegar this basename works in linux only i guess..my program is for cross platform. right now  <libgen.h> is doesnt exist for me.

Answer (score 0):

here i am posting answer of my question so that someone get help from it

```
char path_buffer[] = __FILE__;
    char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
    char dir[_MAX_DIR];
    char fname[_MAX_FNAME];
    char ext[_MAX_EXT];

    _splitpath(path_buffer, drive, dir, fname, ext);

    strcpy(fname, "AvailableUsage");
    strcpy(ext, ".csv");

    _makepath(path_buffer, drive, dir, fname, ext);

    FILE *fp = fopen(path_buffer, "r");
```